# manifest file xamarin ios app

Tags: ios, xamarin, manifest

On Visual Studio 2017 Community with Xamarin (on windows 10), when I try to publish the IOS app (ad-hoc), VS give the following error message:

```
file 'obj\iPhone\Ad-Hoc\myapp.IOS.exe.manifest' not found.
```

The problem is just when I try to publish the IOS app because the manifest file is missing (with public procedure, the clickonce setting is activated by default).

If I try to run in debug mode connecting my Macbook via Xamarin Mac Agent everything works. If I try to compile the app switching off the option Clickonce safety setting it works, so I think my Apple profiles for developer and ad-hoc distribution are working perfectly.